# How do I change the screen brightness on a Windows 7 Lenovo Thinkpad?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I need to add brightness to my screen on a Windows 7 Laptop Lenovo Thinkpad.

How do I do it? It is not comfortable to read anymore and I am straining my eyes.

Comment: Did you try going into Power Management and increasing the brightness, or using the Fn key combination? It could also be in the Display settings...

Comment: Are you talking about a situation where the brightness is still in a "normal" range and you don't know where to find the settings to tweak it, or you know where to adjust it, but the display is dying and barely visible and you're looking for a serious adjustment that you can do without taking it in for service?  Do you have the issue while it is plugged in or only on battery?  Does the brightness stay constant or does it fade over the course of use?

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I change the screen brightness on a Windows 7 Lenovo Thinkpad?

> - To increase the brightness setting of your ThinkPad LCD display, press and hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, then press the <kbd>Home</kbd>
>     key.
> - To decrease the brightness, press and hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, then press the <kbd>End</kbd> key.
>
> The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is typically located at the bottom-left of your
>   keyboard and looks like this:
>
> [image: Fn key]
>
> Note:
>
> - Some ThinkPad LCDs will automatically dim when the AC Power is unplugged. This is to save battery power and is normal.

Source [How to adjust the brightness of the LCD display - ThinkPad](https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/documents/ht003750)

Comment: And I was here thinking the display had lost brightness due to ageing and the Q were about whether any compensation were possible.

Comment: @ClassStacker You could be right, the question is unclear on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Different Lenovo models use different keys for this function.  For example, my X1 uses <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> in conjunction with the Fn key.

Another example below.

[image: Brightness Keys]

You're looking for the sun-like icons somewhere on your keyboard. In some cases the brightness controls are the primary function of the key with no need to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.